# Gems installed with the --user-install option into the OS X home folder aren't working properly afterwards.

Tags: macos, terminal, ruby, rubygems

On previous OS X revisions i had installed my gems with sudo. With Yosemite i wanted to change that and install without sudo. To leave the default gems in

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

and put the ones i want to install into the third folder

```
 /Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
```

The three are listed as GEM PATHS returned by the `gem environment` command. The install worked fine. Afterwards i've added the path variable to my bash_profile:

```
export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

i've installed Sass, Compass and a few more other Compass related gems. When i try to run compass watch inside the Terminal i get:

```
[myuser@localhost][project] compass watch
LoadError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- sassy-math
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
[myuser@localhost][project]
```

Same if try to run Compass from within Codekit.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/danton/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

It seems the gems within my userfolder aren't noticed at all. Is there a way to get things going in that setup or do i have to revert to the sudo install? :/

Comment: Have you tried the `GEM_PATH` environment variable? E.g. `GEM_PATH=/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0 compass watch`. See [this](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment) (scroll down a ways or search the page for `GEM_PATH`)

Comment: hm in my gem environment the paths are already set to: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`  and `/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0`  and `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0` . so basically it should work (but is not). and is it possible to set a binary in the gem_path including an option like watch? couldn't find anything related in the linked doc file.